# why function returning value when there is no return type specified?

Tags: c, function, return, return-value, return-type

```
fun(int x) {
    if(x<=0) return 1; 
    return fun(x-1)+x;
}

void main() 
{
     int a = fun(7);
     printf(" %d",a);
     getch();
}
```

I have this simple code of `C` in this function `fun` is returning value but i have not specified any return type. As per my knowledge default return type is `void`

Comment: Use `int main` instead of `void main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `C` language, by default the `return` type of function is `int`. If you don't return an int from such functions (No explicit return type), the behavior is undefined.

Comment: what in case of c++

Comment: C++ is strict and provides no implicit return type. i.e. you always need to explicitly declare the function before using it with explicit return type. This is adopted in latest C specs also.

Comment: but when i save my code as `.cpp` also it is returning value

Comment: @GoldyAgarwal Which compiler and compile time options are you using? ISO C++ forbids such declarations.

Comment: That's the nature of undefined behaviour. Other compilers might eat your cat.

Comment: @Bathsheba You summed it all ;)

Comment: @MohitJain i am using `DevC++`

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing called *deafult return type*, in this case, the return type has been omitted and compiler has chosen to treat that as `int`.<sup>Note</sup>

**TL;DR** This is invalid code, as per latest C standards.

Quoting `C99` Foreword, p7

> Major changes in the second edition included:
>
> - ......
> - — remove implicit `int`

That said, standard also mandates, for a hosted environment, signature of `main()` should be `int main(void)`, at least.

---

NOTE:

Pre C-99 allowed an *omitted type* to default to `int` and some compilers might still support that to maintain compatibility to legacy code. Do not rely or try to use this *feature*.